# How add extension/css/js to the parent theme?

Tags: luma-theme, parent-child-theme, hyva

I am quite new to magento :)

We are using an external theme (hyva) which inherits from luma. This external theme does not have a checkout module, so when we navigate to the checkout form, it falls back to the parent theme.

Now I need to edit the checkout form. But I don't know where to add my files.
If I put it inside `app/design/Vendor/Theme/...`, it will be added to the child theme.
Where should I put my edited file, to make it add to the parent theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple things is that :

1. If you want to make the changes for child theme then put the files into :

> app\design\frontend\Vendor\ChileTheme\

2. If you want to make the changes for parent theme then put the files into :

> app\design\frontend\Vendor\ParentTheme\

Comment: thanks! I'll try it.

Comment: sure, if answer help please upvote and accept as solution, so it will help other in community.

Answer (score 0):

Hyvä currently uses a React based Checkout, but according to the HyväCamp there will be another way to get your Checkout working.

https://github.com/magewirephp/magewire

Answer (score 0):

To enable Luma Theme Fallback, you should create a custom theme that is based on the Luma theme. Additionally, you need to specify the path of this custom theme in the backend.

Furthermore, you must whitelist the pages that will utilize your custom Luma-based theme.

For more detailed instructions, please refer to the following link.

https://docs.hyva.io/hyva-themes/luma-theme-fallback/

To edit the checkout form, you will need to integrate it within your custom theme, which is based on Luma